# Unable to save a shapefile in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, save

I am working on two shapefiles that I need to modify in **ArcGIS.**

Sometimes ArcGIS simply doesn't open the shapefiles. The error shows the opening feature class message.

Then, while trying to save them, if I just use the Save as a command, I get a **.xmd file**.

Now, I go to the layer and try Export Data, and re-write the output feature class from `"\\Mac\Home\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\..."` to `"\\Mac\Home\Documents\ArcGIS\blablabla.shp"`.

I got the shapefiles, however; there was a random one with some polygons missing, etc. and which it doesn't take into account my modifications.

Does someone know how can I fix this?

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: Try stop editing, and answer yes on Save edits question. Also your software might not like bla name. Just a thought.

Comment: [@Bjorn](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/6845/bjorn), looks like ArcGIS, is not it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way that ArcGIS (presumably ArcMap) is creating a file with an **.xmd** extension. If you are working in ArcMap and you use the **Save as** menu item, you will create an **.mxd** file, or "map document" file.

Importantly, map documents do not contain data. So if you edit the **shapefiles** in ArcMap, but save the **map document**, you are not actually saving your shapefile edits.

The question lacks enough information to tell if this is exactly what is going, but this is my strong suspicion. I strongly suggest that you refer to the documentation and possibly complete a tutorial on editing data in ArcGIS. It will not only show you what to do, it will introduce you to the terminology that you will need to ask clear questions on GIS.SE.

- [ArcGIS Fundamentals of Editing](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/adding-the-editor-toolbar.htm)
- [ArcMap Editing Tutorial](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/introduction-to-the-editing-tutorial.htm)